# java bindingResult hasError function

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, binding, annotations

I have a bean that have some attributes with annotations for certain fields.
I use this bean two times 
The first time I need to use bindingResult.hasError function on all attributes(no problem).
The second time I just want to use bindingResult.hasError function on four attributes (corresponding to the four fields who are displayed by my JSP) but it's not working cause the function bindingResult.hasError detect errors on other fields in the bean

My bean :

```
private String region;
@NotBlank
private String zone;
@NotBlank
private String country;
@NotBlank
private String site;
private Long siteId;
@NotNull
private Long statusId;
private String status;
@NotBlank
private String linkName;
@NotNull
private Long linkTypeId;
private String linkType;
private Integer downloadLineBw;
private Integer downloadPortBw;
private String technology;
@ValidDate
private String installDate; 
private String maintenanceInfo;
private String internetConfiguration;
@NotNull
private Long linkRoleId;
private String linkRole;
private Long contractOwnerId;
private String contractOwner;
private Integer uploadPortBw;
private Integer uploadLineBw;
private Long yearlyCost;
@ValidDate
private String endDate;
private String supplier;
private Long ismCost;
private Long oneTimeCost;
private String linkedService;
```

My controller :

```
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String findLinksByCriteria(@Valid LinkForm link, BindingResult bindingResult, Model uiModel) {
    if (isCriteriaEmpty(link)) {
        uiModel.addAttribute("criteriaEmptyWarning", "error_search_criteria_empty");
        return ViewConstants.LINK_SEARCH_VIEW;
    }
    if (bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
        return ViewConstants.LINK_SEARCH_VIEW;
    }
    ...
}
```

A part of my JSP :

```
        <tr>
            <td class="label"><spring:message code="link.site" /></td> 
            <td class="value"><form:input path="site" cssClass="x-form-text" /></td> 

            <td class="label"><spring:message code="link.type" /></td>
            <td class="value"><form:input path="linkType" cssClass="x-form-text" /></td> 
        </tr> 
        <tr>
            <td class="label"><spring:message code="link.installDate" /></td>
            <td class="value">
                <form:input path="installDate"  cssClass="datepickerMe" />
                <form:errors path="installDate" cssClass="errormsg" />
            </td>


            <td class="label"><spring:message code="link.EndDate" /></td>
            <td class="value">
                <form:input  path="endDate" cssClass="datepickerMe" />
                <form:errors path="endDate" cssClass="errormsg" />
            </td>
        </tr>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's possible to create a custom spring validator so you can determine witch attributes should be validated:

```
@Controller
public class MyController {

    @Autowired
    private MyFormValidador formValidador;

    @InitBinder
    private void initBinder(WebDataBinder binder) {
        binder.setValidator(formValidador);
    }

    @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String execute(@Valid MyForm form, BindingResult result, Model model) {
        if (result.hasErrors()) {
            return "errorview";
        }

        return "successview";
    }

}

@Component
public class MyFormValidador implements Validator {

    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> clazz) {
        return MyForm.class.isAssignableFrom(clazz);
    }

    @Override
    public void validate(Object target, Errors errors) {
        ValidationUtils.rejectIfEmptyOrWhitespace(errors, "linkName", "linkName.required", "Link name must be informed");
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, do you know if it is better to create custom spring validator or a new java bean for my form ?

Comment: I personally prefer duplicate the form since the intent of the class will become clearer and easier to maintain (e.g. `CreateLinkForm`, `EditLinkForm`)

Comment: Is the way I finally chose. Thank you for help

Answer (score 0):

In Spring, BindingResult looks for the complete object errors, you cant check errors for partial object(few fields in the object).

In an object if any single validation failed then `bindingResult.hasError()` will return `true`, hence validation for object failed. `bindingResult.hasError()` will be `false` only if all validations in the object are satisfied.

Its kind of Creating a DB Table with columns `NOT NULL` property and trying to insert `NULL` value for those columns.